# How to implement a Rich Text Editor with uploadable images anywhere inside text

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, upload

I would like to implement a RTE (Rich Text Editor) with the ability to upload images anywhere inside the text. My aim is to create an "add / edit news article" page, where the client can write a story with images.

I am good at PHP and Javascript programming, so I am looking for help about *methods* of implementing this. Do I create a custom button in this RTE to insert a previously uploaded image or some other way? How do I display those images for the user to choose? Etc.

Bonus points for:

- Multiple files upload: the ability for the client to just select e.g. 10 images that are relevant to this story.
- Uses some method other than Flash as a default for upload.
- Uses jQuery as I use it a lot.
- RTE is very lightweight. I don't care if the client has to know a few things (like markdown or something similar), I just don't like bloated RTEs.
- Uses new technologies, like HTML5 and / or CSS3.

Let me clarify a few things. I know a few Javascript RTEs and have also *used* them in several CMSs. So I don't need links to these, I can Google "javascript RTE" myself :). However, something like @hakre said *is* useful as he pointed out how extensible CKEditor is, which I was not fully aware.

To give an example of the answer I'm looking for: "you can do this with CKEditor, upload images asynchronously with jquery-html5-upload, save all uploaded image filename in a Javascript array, create a new button inside CKEditor with a custom click handler, which displays an overlay with Fancybox and you show all the images (you have filenames stored in an array), user clicks an image and you insert html into the editor".
Something like that but better :) (or should I say accurate).

Comment: What did you do so far? This is not a `get a free programmer` forum...

Comment: Anything in here that meets with your reqs? http://ckeditor.com/developer-features

Comment: @hakre: yes, it does. I'm gonna have to take a closer look at this. I will also edit my question to clarify a few things. You can make this into an answer (maybe more elaborate one? :)) and I'll vote you up.

Comment: I have just found out about jwysiwyg, which is a jQuery RTE plugin and is veeeery extensible, open and feels modern. It also has a well thought of uploading and insert image capabilities. I think this will be a part of my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything in here that meets with your reqs? http://ckeditor.com/developer-features

Answer (score 0):

You taken a look at [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)?

Comment: I have updated my question with an example of what I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

The "fake answer" you gave yourself is quite accurate. You would need a RTE editor that supports custom functionality.

The logistics would go along these lines:

1. User presses a button
2. An empty div is appended to the input with a unique id
3. An image uploader popup will open, with pointers to the new div
4. A combination of jQuery / AJAX / PHP will allow the user to upload a file within the page
5. The filename is returned after the upload process and inserted in the originally appended div

If you are looking for the specific code for each of these steps, I would recommend finding some tutorials as this isn't something that we can write some fast example code for.

Comment: I'm not looking for code, but this is still too vague. I do need _some_ implementation details, like what projects go together, etc.

Comment: Well, you said you could google javascript RTE yourself. What you'd need is (like I said) a RTE editor that supports custom functionality. Then you'd need an AJAX upload system (specifics not important, as long as it's with AJAX and capable of returning a filename), and just fill the gaps.

Comment: Yes, I think that's obvious. I need something like "use this editor with this uploader, customize this function, etc.".